# What is the <{}> syntax after extends Component?

Tags: react-native, syntax, flowtype

I started a new project today using React Native 0.51.0 and noticed that the class syntax for the default project file had something new added, the `<{}>` syntax after `extends Component`:

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
   ...
}
```

I tried doing research but most search engines ignore special characters even with exact string matching, so trying to find out what this syntax is has proved to be difficult. I did some testing and was able to figure out that this change appeared in v0.49.0. The [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.49.0) make no mention of what this added syntax does though.

A lot of vague keyword searching and reading leads me to believe that this may be syntax related to TypeScript, but being unfamiliar with the language, I'm at a loss as to how to search and find out more about the syntax without knowing what the proper term for it is. Could anyone tell me what the name of the syntax and what it does? Specifically with regards to React Native.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is related to [Flow](https://flow.org/) typings for the props you will receive in the component. `Component<{}>` would mean that you don't expect the component to receive props.

With Flow and `React.Component`, you can define types for props and state (see [React$Component](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.61.0/lib/react.js#L26) type declaration for details).

*Example from Flow [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/) about React components*

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = { /* ... */ };

type State = {
  count: number,
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        count: prevState.count + 1,
      }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Count: {this.state.count}</div>;
  }
}

<MyComponent />;
```